# XPages: one template, two memory models?

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I'd like to maintain one single master template for our XPages application, albeit with 2 different memory models and properties. The development template's model (master) should be on disk, no JS optimization and no dojo compression. The model in the derived template, to be used in client applications, we configure as in memory, optimized JS and compressed dojo.

When set the configuration parameters differently in each template and then refresh the design of the derived template, both templates end up identical (which might seem logical). What I mean: it is not possible to prohibit the XSP settings to be refreshed, like one can set on other elements.

But even if there were such a possibility, it isn't going to work because everything should be recompiled ("clean") otherwise the compressed JS and css aren't properly generated. I found no way to start a compilation on the derived template automatically.

Or is there a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Source control and branching should be the right way to handle it: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_srcecontrol_top.html

Old fashioned way would be to "branch" your templates. Master template for your XSP development, and second template inheriting from the first one. In second template [set](http://www2.ytria.com/NotesDomino/helpsite/designPropEZ-features-update) "Prohibit design refresh or ..." property for XSP.properties design element. Then change its content to fit your needs.

## Here's the story

Once upon a time there was a team of developers working on several databases, some of them marked as template for further deployment to production. One developer wanted to reuse some elements from another database - template. Copied, and pasted them into another database. Designer prompted: "Do you want to inherit design from template ...?". Ehm, no. So designer did not flag the design element with template name, what's OK. In addition, designer sets "Prohibit design refresh..." flag, though. Nobody noticed, until release day! New application behaves weirdly, some parts got updated, some not. It was quite easy to discover that "Prohibit..." flag was set, and fix it. But weirdness continues. And guess what? This flag was set on elements not having such check box in designer's GUI (in this case Java sources).

## What worked

Create special view showing design elements http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/view-of-design-elements.htm.

Create another column showing, what elements are prohibited to refresh. Set "Display values as icon".

```
"Prohibit design refresh or replace to modify";
@If( @Contains( $Flags; "P" ); 80; 0 ) : @If( @Contains( $Flags; "r" ); 204; 0 )
```

Create a view action working with selected documents (`ss.CurrentDatabase.UnprocessedDocuments` for ticked ones, `uiv.CaretNoteID` and `GetDocumentByID` for focused only) and call this code to reset the flag.

```
Sub Prohibit(note As NotesDocument)
    On Error Goto errHandler

    Dim flags As String
    Dim flagsNew As String
    flags = note.GetItemValue( "$Flags" )(0)
    flagsNew = Replace( flags, "P", "" )
    If flags <> flagsNew Then
        note.ReplaceItemValue "$Flags", flagsNew
        note.Save True, False
    End If

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    Print "Error on " & note.UniversalID & " (" & note.GetItemValue( "$Title" )(0) & ")"
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

**Disclaimer:** in some cases this breaks element's signature - forced sign of whole database fixes it.

**Note**: That prompt about inheritance - it sets the flag "Prohibit..." if you answer **No** when copying FROM template TO template - even if it is the same database!

## Conclusion

So, in your case, make the opposite - just set the flag by adding `"P"` to `$Flags` field of `XSP.properties` file. By the way, its `$TITLE` field is `"WEB-INF/xsp.properties"`.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, but... AFAIK, there is no "Prohibit" thing for XSP.properties. I also checked using the Navigator: no checkbox there, nothing.

Comment: There is no such option in designer GUI. It is stored as ordinary design note, though. You have to use tool like Ytria (preffered) or a bit of hacking with NotesNote.

Comment: I like the "hacking" suggestion... :-)

Comment: If it were an ordinary design note, wouldn't it have a note id? It doesn't, so maybe it's stored somewhere else, together with other design elements? Anyway, I can't find it (yet).